# my background image is not visible in render mode and I need the HDRI to still be visible

Tags: rendering, camera, hdri

So I'm trying to render some lightning striking on a building (the building being in the HDRI) and I want to add a rain overlay to it. But in the render, the overlay won't show and there are no tutorials on this exact situation.

Here are some pictures:

Here it is in viewport mode:
[image: viewport mode]

And here it is in render mode:
[image: render mode]

I want the render mode to look like the viewport one.

EDIT: Here is the .blend file: https://ufile.io/blvc9t4z

Comment: How are you adding the overlay? That should be fairly simple using compositing.

Comment: I'm adding a background image to the camera in blender , maybe I should try with a video editor or something.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know those background images do not show up in renders ever. I was fairly disappointed about that, but it is easy to do in compositing.

Comment: please provide the blend file

Comment: Here you go, I've added the file.